# How can I use djcelery.schedulers without Django project?

Tags: python, celery, djcelery

I want to use dynamic scheduler management for celery. I know djcelery have that functionality with database support.
But currently I do not use Django, but Flask. I couldn't find out Flask project or implementation with djcelery.schedulers.

Is it possible to use djcelery and implement dynamic scheduler management system without Django?

Comment: When you say "dynamic scheduler management", what do you mean?  Changing the task set at runtime?  This sounds like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat](this).

Comment: Yes, I mean something like that question. Specifically, I want to add the task with arguments and runtime to celery via API and remove that task also via API.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, but...

You have to use django. The scheduler's entries are instances of django models so you would have to setup djcelery app somehow (see this code: https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/schedulers.py) Also you won't have the admin interface to add scheduler's entries.

This is just a guess, but you can try setting django's ORM standalone and syncing djcelery's models. (see:  [Use Django ORM as standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937742/use-django-orm-as-standalone))

You can also implement your own scheduler following the structure of djcelery/schedulers.py

Also see: [Can celery celerybeat use a Database Scheduler without Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760250/can-celery-celerybeat-use-a-database-scheduler-without-django)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to replace Django ORM of djcelery with SQLAlchemy. If you know the project of SQLAlchemy with djcelery, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [flask-djcelery](https://github.com/waqasjaved160/flask-djcelery). It configures djcelery with flask, allows using django admin and also provide a browseable rest api for managing tasks.